# How to prove the following inequality (log)

Tags: inequality, logarithms

How to Prove the following inequality:
$$\ln { \sum _{ i }{ { e }^{ { { c }_{ i } } } }  } \ge \frac { \sum _{ i }{ { c }_{ i }{ e }^{ { c }_{ i } } }  }{ \sum _{ i }{ { e }^{ { c }_{ i } } }  } ,\quad { c }_{ i }<0$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function $\phi:[0, \infty) \to \Bbb R$ defined by
$$
 \phi(t) = \begin{cases}
 0 & \text{ for } t = 0 \\
 -t \ln(t) & \text{ for } t > 0
\end{cases}
$$
is concave ($\phi''(t) = -\frac 1t < 0$ for $t > 0$) with $\phi(0) \ge 0$, and
therefore *subadditive* (compare [Concave function – Properties](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concave_function#Functions_of_a_single_variable)). It follows that
$$
 \phi\left(\sum_{i=1}^n t_i \right) \le \sum_{i=1}^n \phi(t_i)
$$
for any $t_1, \ldots, t_n \ge 0$.

Choosing $t_i = e^{c_i}$ gives:
$$
 - \left( \sum_{i=1}^n e^{c_i} \right)  \cdot \ln \left(\sum_{i=1}^n e^{c_i} 
\right) \le  \sum_{i=1}^n \left( - e^{c_i} c_i\right)
$$
which is the desired inequality. The assumption $c_i < 0$ is not needed.

---

*Simpler solution,* inspired by [gimusi's answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2604613/42969): For each $1 \le i \le n$
$$
 e^{c_i} \cdot \ln \left(\sum_{j=1}^n e^{c_j}\right) \ge  e^{c_i} \cdot \ln e^{c_i} = c_i  e^{c_i} \, .
$$
Adding these inequalities gives the desired 
$$
\left( \sum_{i=1}^n e^{c_i} \right) \cdot \ln \left(\sum_{j=1}^n e^{c_j}\right) \ge \sum_{i=1}^n c_i e^{c_i} \, .
$$
It is easy to see that the inequality is *strict* if $n \ge 2$.

Comment: Maybe the domain of the function $\phi$ should be $[0, +\infty]$, since $\sum_{i=1}^n {t_i}$ could be large than 1.

Comment: @Macer: You are right! So the assumption that all $c_i$ are negative is actually not needed.

Comment: Indeed in this way it becames almost a trivial fact, well done!

Answer (score 2):

Let indicate

$$c_i=\ln x_i \quad x_i\in(0,1)$$

thus

$$\ln { \sum _{ i }{ { e }^{ { { c }_{ i } } } }  } \ge \frac { \sum _{ i }{ { c }_{ i }{ e }^{ { c }_{ i } } }  }{ \sum _{ i }{ { e }^{ { c }_{ i } } }  }\iff \ln \left(\sum_ix_i\right) \ge \frac{\sum_i \left(x_i \ln x_i\right)}{\sum_i x_i}
\\\iff \ln \left[\left(\sum_ix_i\right)^{\sum_i x_i}\right] \ge \sum_i \ln x_i^{x_i}
\iff e^{\ln \left[\left(\sum_ix_i\right)^{\sum_i x_i}\right]} \ge e^{\sum_i \ln x_i^{x_i}}
\\\iff \left(\sum_ix_i\right)^{\sum_i x_i}\ge\prod_i x_i^{x_i}
$$

which is true indeed

$$\left(\sum_ix_i\right)^{\sum_i x_i}=(x_1+x_2+...+x_n)^{(x_1+x_2+...+x_n)}= (x_1+x_2+...+x_n)^{x_1}\cdot(x_1+x_2+...+x_n)^{x_2}\cdot ...\cdot(x_1+x_2+...+x_n)^{x_n} \ge x_1^{x_1}\cdot x_2^{x_2}\cdot...\cdot x_n^{x_n}= \prod_i x_i^{x_i}$$

**Note**: the hypothesis that $c_i<0$ is unnecessary

Comment: Thanks for the anwser, but isn't $c_1\leq c_2\leq...\leq c_n\iff e^{c_i} \ge e^{c_j}\le...\le e^{c_n}$ supposed to be $c_1\leq c_2\leq...\leq c_n\iff e^{c_1} \leq e^{c_2}\leq...\leq e^{c_n}$

Comment: note that for $c_i<0$ $$c_1<c_2 \implies e^{c_1}>e^{c_2}$$

Comment: @gimusi: No, the exponential function is strictly increasing for *all* $x \in \Bbb R$.

Comment: @MartinR ops ...of course sorry! thus the inequality does not hold

Comment: Your updated answer states $\ln { \sum _{ i }{ { e }^{ { { c }_{ i } } } }  }\ge \frac{\sum c_i}{n}\leq \frac{\sum c_i\cdot e^{c_i}}{\sum e^{c_i}}$, but nothing can be concluded from that.

Comment: @MartinRI mean that we can't conclude by Chebyshev's Inequality, any idea to fix better?

Comment: @MartinR Thanks I try to fix it!

Comment: @MartinR I've fixed my proof (I hope), in that case convexity wasn't a good way to prove!

Comment: @gimusi: Yes, this works (+1). Based on your approach I have shortened the proof even further.

Comment: Thanks it’s was a nice collaboration with you!